# How to setup Azure DevOps with IntelliJ and Illuminated Cloud for Salesforce Development?

Tags: azure, illuminatedcloud, intellij

We are using IntelliJ with the Illuminated Cloud plugin for Salesforce development. We have decided to use Azure DevOps git repository for our VCS. This is a fresh, empty repo and I cannot figure out how to add our code (just the 'src' folder) to the repo and get it all connected up.

I have installed the Azure DevOps plugin inside IntelliJ and I can see the repo. However, I don't know what the next step is to get my current IntelliJ / Illuminated Cloud project connected so I can perform my initial commit. What I have tried is perform an initial Clone, but this ends up creating blank project without the Illuminated Cloud "nature".

Can someone provide the high level steps I need to take to setup IntelliJ and Azure DevOps and perform my initial checkin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this topic from the user guide?

https://bitbucket.org/RoseSilverSoftware/illuminatedcloud/wiki/User_Guide/Create_Project_Version_Control.md

It details how to create an IC project from an existing version control (typically Git) repo. I do that all the time. IC will help to convert the project/module for its own use.

Regards,
Scott Wells

Comment: Thanks Scott. Turns out I first needed to seed my repo with Salesforce metadata before I was able complete these steps.